# Jquery Jqgrid: have the grid dynamically grow to 20 rows and then show a scroll bar to view 20+

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to create a grid with;

rowNum:  20,
height:  "100%"

so that if grid has 10 items and a new item is added, the grid will grow by one row.  repeat this till it gets to 20 rows, and then display vertical scrollbar to view 20+ items.

Comment: If you mean jqGrid with local data, then you will be able to go to the next page after the grid will have 20+ items. So you will have local paging instead of vertical scrollbar.

Comment: I'm using jqGrid with remote data.  and using the pager is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with css and a `max-height` attribute. The `max-height` needs to be `(20*rowHeight)`.

for example, on [this page](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) run the following code in the console:

```
$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css({height: 'auto', 'max-height': 300});
```

Selecting the overflow container, remove the static height, set a max height. Just change the `300` to whatever height 20 rows is. I would see if you can define this in a style sheet.

Comment: sorry, don't understand all of your steps. a) I went to the "this page", jqGrid Demos, but do not see a console.  b) what is the overflow container?  c) for the grid itself, do I remove rowNum and height options.

Comment: @Larry - apologies. The console is a firebug and chrome tool (or IE9). In chrome CTRL+SHIFT+J will bring up the developer console. An overflow container is the html element that allows for scroll bars `overflow:auto`. Yes you can remove the rowNum and height options.

Comment: Josiah, thanks for explanation. I have got it to work, it will now auto grow in height. but the grid is only displaying 20 rows, which is the default for rowNum. I want it to list 20+ rows. my remote datasource is returning 24 rows, only 20 is displayed.

Comment: I think I have the solution.  set rowNum: -1

Comment: what would the code be for IE?  IE does not recognize the max-height.  the height is auto, no scroll